# Разделить строку по символу ; не разделяя по ; внутри слова окружённого кавычками

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.
Как написать выражение re.split, которое будет делить строку по символу ; (точка с запятой) при условие, что этот символ не есть частью одного слова?

Пример:

```
Название;"Дат;а";Человек;
Грив;22,14;"Пе;тя"
```

Должно поделить на:

```
Название, Дат;а, Человек,
Грив, 22,14, Пе;тя
```

Я понимаю, что пример очень фантастичен ( нет слов, в которые входит символ ; ), но, надеюсь, понятно обьяснил.

Спасибо.

Comment: Обновил ответ, ознакомьтесь

Answer (score 4):

В таких случаях [удобно cvs модуль использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
>>> import csv
>>> lines = 'Название;"Дат;а";Человек;\nГрив;22,14;"Пе;тя"'.splitlines()
>>> list(csv.reader(lines, delimiter=';'))
[['Название', 'Дат;а', 'Человек', ''], ['Грив', '22,14', 'Пе;тя']]
```

Для вывода также можно `csv` можно использовать:

```
>>> rows = csv.reader(lines, delimiter=';')

>>> import sys
>>> csv.writer(sys.stdout).writerows(rows)
Название,Дат;а,Человек,
Грив,"22,14",Пе;тя
```

Обратите внимание, что во второй строчке автоматически используются кавычки, чтобы заэкранировать запятые. Можно другой разделитель использовать, к примеру, пробел:

```
>>> csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=' ').writerows(rows)
Название Дат;а Человек 
Грив 22,14 Пе;тя
```

или использовать специальный экранирующий символ:

```
>>> csv.writer(sys.stdout, escapechar='\\', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE).writerows(rows)
Название,Дат;а,Человек,
Грив,22\,14,Пе;тя
```

В данном случае backslash используется, чтобы заэкранировать запятую (разделитель полей) внутри поля.

Не смотря на простоту, в таком формате могут быть тонкие места, в которых легко ошибиться,  если пытаться самостоятельно распознавать подобный формат, используя свой парсер -- если нет особых причин, лучше уже существующий формат с уже реализованным оттестированным парсером использовать.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае лучше использовать другие модули. Такие, как `csv` или `json`

Но если вы хотите разделить строку по символу с помощью регулярных выражений, вы можете использовать знак отрицания `^`. Примеры:

Разобьём строку по пробелам:

Паттерн: `r'[^ ]+'`

```
result = re.findall(r'[^ ]+', 'Это тестовая строка, чтобы показать как можно разбивать строку по символам')
print(result) # ['Это', 'тестовая', 'строка,', 'чтобы', 'показать', 'как', 'можно', 'разбивать', 'строку', 'по', 'символам']
```

Разобьём строку по запятым:

```
result = re.findall(r'[^,]+', 'Это тестовая строка, чтобы показать как можно разбивать строку по символам')
print(result) # ['Это тестовая строка', ' чтобы показать как можно разбивать строку по символам']
```

Теперь давайте перейдём к вашей строке. У вас очень интересная задача: нужно игнорировать скобки. Но и тут можно справиться, добавив **или**(`|`) в условие поиска нашего паттерна:

```
import re

data = []
lines = ['Название;"Дат;а";Человек;', 'Грив;22,14;"Пе;тя"']

for line in lines:
    result = re.findall(r'(".+?"|[^;]+)', line)
    data.extend(result) # обратите внимание на то, какой у нас вывод
    # когда мы используем функцию extend


print(data) # ['Название', '"Дат;а"', 'Человек', ' Грив', '22,14', '"Пе;тя"']
```

Чтобы избавиться от кавычек можно воспользоваться функцией `sub` из того же модуля `re`. Чтобы не делать кучу списков и не получить ошибку во время замены значений, перед перебором скопируем его. В общем виде у нас получится такой код:

```
import re

data = []
lines = ['Название;"Дат;а";Человек;', 'Грив;22,14;"Пе;тя"']

for line in lines:
    result = re.findall(r'(".+?"|[^;]+)', line)
    result = [re.sub(r'"(.+)"', r'\1', x) for x in result]
    data.append(result) # посмотрите какой вывод при использовании функции append

print(data) # [['Название', 'Дат;а', 'Человек'], ['Грив', '22,14', 'Пе;тя']]
```

**Обратите внимание** на то, что в примерах, при добавлении списка **использовались разные функции**: `extend` и `append`, которые дали разный аутпут.

**Подробнее с регулярными выражениями вы можете ознакомиться [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/115825/) и [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/115436/).**