# Регулярное выражение для поиска русских букв, исключающее определённое слово

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. Работаю в FlashDevelop и в глобальном поиске по проекту (ctrl+shift+f) пишу RegExp (на C#, как я понял), который найдет строки, содержащие выражение вида: кавычка+русскаяБуква*+кавычка. Простая регулярка работает, но очень хочется исключить из выборки строки, содержащие слово 'trace'. Другими словами, я ищу строку, которая не содержит слова trace, но содержит одну или более русскую букву между кавычек. Сразу следует оговорить, что между trace и русской строкой в кавычках может быть что угодно, а до trace множество табуляций.
Примеры:

```
trace("Шла");
trace("error:", id, "Саша");
var s:String = "по шоссе";
var a:Array = [123, "и что-то там"];
```

Рабочая конструкция поиска русских строк в проекте:

```
".*[А-яЁё].*"
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Поробуйте `(?!trace).*[А-яЁё].*`

Comment: @0xdb , результат 627 сообщений. Что так 
(?!trace).*[А-яЁё].*  
, что так 
.*[А-яЁё].*
Именно на применении ?! , ?: , ^ я и застрял.

Comment: Взял из глубин подсазнания, те не проверял, тк на телефоне нет возможности. Но где-то в этом направлении. Поробуйте 2-ю часть тоже в группу.

Comment: Ваша регулярка не сработает на `что-то` (дефис).

Comment: Посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/655859/243273). Может, поможет. **P.S.** RegExp универсальны. И вы скорее на пайтон их пишете (строка сырая)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо пользователю @Wiktor Stribiżew за рабочую регулярку:

```
(?im)^(?!.*\btrace\b).*"[^"\r\n]*[а-яё][^"\r\n]*".*
```

Comment: Куда уже проще?

Comment: А что за "Эти регулярки для поиска строк, а не слов\букв, для замены они не подходят!

Если кто знает, как написать эти регулярки проще - спасибо заранее!"??? Где это в вашем вопросе? Что надо найти? На что заменить?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, этот комментарий был для тех, кто, возможно, будет эти регулярки использовать в своём проекте. Следует заметить, что регулярки не идеальные и выводят такие строчки (из-за точки перед кавычками): trace(0.5, "странно");

Comment: Используйте [`(?im)^(?!.*\btrace\b).*"[^"\r\n]*[а-я][^"\r\n]*".*`](https://regex101.com/r/Rvs2wu/2).

Comment: Да, ё не забудьте добавить в `[а-я]`