# Правильное экранирование спецсимвола в регулярном выражении VisualStudio

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, visual-studio

Приветствую, подсмотрел [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658029/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE/792904#792904) регулярное выражение,
но почему то при добавлении строки

```
string pattern3 = "(? im) ^ (? !.*\bLR.Get\b).*"[^"\r\n]*[а - яё][^ "\r\n]*".*";
```

visual studio пишет:
Недопустимый термин "^" и
Недопустимый символ "\"

Как правильно за экранировать?

Ну и в целом не понятно, проверяю РВ в notepad++ или в visualcode значение находит, а в студию когда копирую пишет что или символы не верные или еще чтото, пример:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[(]["].+["][)]");
```

Comment: У вас кавычка двойная не экранирована, не?

Comment: Перепробовал кучу вариантов и в одинарную все оборачивал и перед кавычкой косую писал...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string pattern3 = "(?im)^(?!.*\\btrace\\b).*\"[^\"\\r\\n]*[а-яё][^\"\\r\\n]*\".*";
```

p.s. В `ReSharper`'e [есть опция](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Smart_Paste.html), которая предлагает все экранизировать в автоматическом порядке, советую...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]