# Как разделить читаемую строку по разделяющему символу без csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, обработка-данных

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655825/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC) уже есть похожий вопрос, но мне требуется решение, которое не подразумевает подключение csv модуля.

Файл на чтение:

```
Петров;85;92
Сидоров;100;88
Иванов;58;72
```

Требуется вывести среднее значение первой и второй пары значений под каждым именем. Я пытаюсь делать это так:

```
file = open('In.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    [print((first + second)/2) for name, first, second in line.split(';')]
```

Но такая конструкция не работает.
Как разделить строку, получаемую в цикле из файла по символу `;`?

Comment: вам принципиально нельзя ползоваться никакими модулями?

Comment: @MaxU не желательно, т.к. только осваиваю этот замечательный язык и хочу уметь в достаточной мере пользоваться встроенным функционалом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filename = r'C:\Temp\data.csv'
sep = ';'
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        vals = line.strip().split(sep)
        avg = sum(map(float, vals[1:])) / len(vals[1:])
        print(f"{vals[0]}: {avg}")
```

Вывод на экран:

```
Петров: 88.5
Сидоров: 94.0
Иванов: 65.0
```

PS решение исходит из того, что в первом столбце - имя (строка), а в остальных столбцах числовые значения. Для каждой строки находится среднее для всех столбцов, кроме первого.

Comment: csv является бинарным файлом, не так ли? Чтение бинарных файлов работает так же как и txt формат?

Comment: @AlexIdest, CSV является __текстовым__ файлом

Comment: @AlexIdest любой файл является бинарным, вопрос лишь в том, можно ли интерпретировать эти бинарные файлы как текст в какой-нибудь кодировке. Код этого ответа подразумевает, что в файле находится текст в кодировке utf-8. Ну и да, csv это текст